Gap forming in retaining wall blocks under patio
Yesterday I noticed a gap in these concrete blocks next to my foundation. Never noticed it before but I guess it could have been there a while. Seems like the ground around my house has sunk a bit. How is this possible and is it a concern?



Assuming that this is just a retaining and support wall for the patio, it's not a concern with respect to the house foundation. It happens because the base for the wall was inadequate (or just due to the persistence of time). The fact that it's adjacent to your foundation is immaterial.
The proper fix is to pull the wall apart in that area, excavate the base and install compacted inorganic material, and reinstall the wall. You could also try levering up the sagging blocks and jamming some gravel underneath, but that's probably going to give unsatisfactory and temporary results.
